# iOS6: Changed behavior when using tel://-url to dial phone number

Tags: ios, nsurl, openurl

I am seeing an undocumented changed behaviour, when using the tel:-URL-Scheme to dial a phone number.

Example

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://232322"]];
```

In iOS4 and iOS5 after the called ended, the user was left in the phone app. In iOS 6 the app, that made the call, is now relaunched. Interestingly making a facetime-Call using the facetime:// URL does not relaunch the app. Not very consistent:)
Does anyone know how to control that behaviour, so it behaves like under iOS4/iOS5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, the implementation is totally up to the app that response the URL scheme. In the case of the `tel:` scheme it's the dialer.

Since Apple does have not released any scheme parameter for `tel:` there is no way to control the behavior of the dialer.